# Form is not sending through ajax to php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I created a form with inputs inside of it that I am trying to send via an ajax call to a php form to allow me to get the email.

From looking at my network tab, I am not seeing my php file `email-project.php` show up, unless I am looking in the wrong location. I am uncertain of what it is that I am doing wrong. The only error I am getting is an unexpected token for this line in my ajax variables:

`var project-name       = $("#project-name").val();`

Does anyone see what is wrong?

```
<form action="" autocomplete="on" method="POST" id="project-information-form">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-name" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="title-roll" placeholder="Title/Role">
    <input type="email" class="input-borderless" id="project-email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-number" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-company" placeholder="Company/URL">
</div>
<div class="project-input-container2">
    <textarea rows="3" class="input-borderless" id="project-description" placeholder="Describe the project"></textarea>
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-source" placeholder="How did you hear about us?">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-socialMedia" placeholder="Which of our social media influenced you the most?">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-humanTest" placeholder="Human Test: What day comess after Thursday?">
</div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit-project" value="Send Project Inquiry">
</form>
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#submit-project").on("click", function () {
        var project_name        = $("#project-name").val();
        var title_roll          = $("#title-roll").val();
        var project_email       = $("#project-email").val();
        var project_number      = $("#project-number").val();
        var project_company     = $("#project-company").val();
        var project_description = $("#project-description").val();
        var project_source      = $("#project-source").val();
        var project_socialMedia = $("#project-socialMedia").val();
        var project_humanTest   = $("#project-humanTest").val();        
        $.ajax({
            url: "email-project.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "project_name":         project_name,
                "title_roll":           title_roll,
                "project_email":        project_email,
                "project_number":       project_number,
                "project_description":  project_description,
                "project_source":       project_source,
                "project_socialMedia":  project_socialMedia,
                "project_humanTest":    project_humanTest
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //  console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
                if (data == "Error!") {
                    alert("Unable to send email!");
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                    $(".announcement_success").show();
                    $('.announcement_success').html('Announcement Successfully Added!');
                    $('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
                //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$project_name           = $_POST['project_name'];
$title_roll             = $_POST['title_roll'];
$project_email          = $_POST['project_email'];
$project_number         = $_POST['project_number'];
$project_description    = $_POST['project_description'];
$project_source         = $_POST['project_source'];
$project_socialMedia    = $_POST['project_socialMedia'];
$project_humanTest      = $_POST['project_humanTest'];

$to = 'email';
$subject = 'Project Inquiry Form Sent';
$message = 'FROM: '.$project_name. "<br>" . ' Email: '.$project_email. "<br>" . 'Message: '.$project_description;
$headers = 'From:' .$project_email . "\r\n";

if (!empty($email)) { 
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 

        //Should also do a check on the mail function
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
        } else {
            echo "Mail could not be sent!"; // failed message
        }

    } else { 
        //Invalid email
        echo "Invalid Email, please provide a valid email address.";
    }

} else {
    echo "Email Address was not filled out.";
}
```

[image]

Comment: JS Tutorial 101: Variable names can only contain alphabets, numbers and underscores.

Comment: @Tushar ha wow! That is a silly mistake.

Comment: @Tushar Even when I replace all of the hyphens with underscores, it still doesn't send and the email-project.php file does not show in my network tab.

Comment: Question updated. I do not have any errors in the conole.

Comment: `form` is submitted and page is redirected. You need to use `event.preventDefault()` or `return false;` in the submit button event handler to stop that.

Comment: @Tushar I did this ` $("#submit-project").on("click", function () {
  event.preventDefault();` and still nothing.

Comment: look in console at error thrown ....event is not global in all browsers, need to add as argument to event handler. Also can greatly simplify collecting data to send by using names on elements and `serialize()`. Should always have name on form controls

Comment: @charlietfl There is not an error thrown. How can I add an argument to it?

Comment: `$("#submit-project").on("click", function (event) ...`

Comment: @charlietfl So even with that : `$("#submit-project").on("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();` , it still isn't sending anything to my php file.

Comment: is request being made...inspect in dev tools network. Is page still refreshing?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, the page is still refreshing. The request is not being made. I updated my questions with a screen shot of the network tab, after I submitted this.

Comment: does this form exist when page loads? Are you duplicating ID's anyhwere? Try `alert($("#submit-project").length)` in page load code

Comment: OK...and no errors anywhere in console before submit? Question says you had one. Errors will block other code running

Comment: I guess there was an error on there. It was for a script I had at the top of the page, that I forgot was even there. It is now submitting to my php form, but it is saying the email wasn't filled out when it was.

Comment: Nvm, I got it! Thank you for all the help. Feel free to make an answer.